# not getting proper image in React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a problem with my reaction time.

If I open my product page for the first time, everything is OK except the photo.[Not working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwKLd.png)

As you can see in the image,

But if I refresh the page, it works perfectly fine. [working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB9zd.png)

**my product page component**

Comment: You should use keys . I think it will solve your issue .
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-keys/

Comment: I've already included a key in my Carousel component.